# Cannot find certfile

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I've been facing a problem while launching my emulator in Android Studio
these 2 lines appear:

> Emulator: **emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\HP.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.**
> **Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554.**

And then all I see on my phone is "*HELLO WORD*"

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the AVD Manager in Android Studio by selecting Tools > AVD Manager menu. In the opened popup, choose Wipe Data option as can be seen below image. After that, restart emulator, hope it would work.

[image: AVD Manager Image]